# Loading two different textures in Android openGL es

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to load multiple textures in my Applikation. The Problem is that the second texture isnt displayed right.
This is how i get the Handels:

```
 mTextureDataHandle = TextureHelper.loadTexture(mActivityContext, R.drawable.full_texture);
 mTextureDataHandleError = TextureHelper.loadTexture(mActivityContext, R.drawable.full_texture_error);
```

using this Method:

```
public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0 )
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();                       
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

during the onDrawFrame method I use this to switch between Textures:

```
    if (LessonFourActivity.error) {
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandleError);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 1);
    } else {
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
    }
```

The texture without the error works fine but when i switch to the error texture it's just black.
Does anyone know an answer to this?

I already found a few answers regarding GL10 but they didnt help me.

Comment: Try removing the active texture and always use GL_TEXTURE0. You use active texture when you need multiple textures in your shader at the same time. Beside that try using only the error texture to se if there is an issue with the resource.

Comment: The error Picture works fine all alone but i'll try it without the activeTexture tomorrow and post the result thank you :)

Comment: It did work :) Took me a few days to realise two other mistakes in other methods but your help made it thanks a lot :)